# change date label by user

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm using C#.net to program a reservation system

I want to let the user change date through the arrows as shown on the picture (please click on the link)

**date image**

[image]

I have done from displaying the current date on the screen but I just don't know how to let the user use the arrows to change the dates 
these are the html codes:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblServerDateTime" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style13" style="font-size:30px;" />
```

and these are the **C#** code

```
protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblServerDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M");
}
```

Comment: `page_load` is this javascript code?

Comment: How you would know the year of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippets may help you:

**Aspx**

```
 <asp:Button Text="Down" ID="btnDown" runat="server" OnClick="btnDown_Click" />
 <asp:Label ID="lblServerDateTime" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style13" Style="font-size: 30px;" />
 <asp:Button Text="UP" ID="btnUp" runat="server" OnClick="btnUp_Click" />
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lblServerDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM");
            calCurrentDay.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
            // Sets current date on initially.
        }
    }

protected void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Up button click will increase the date by one day
        DateTime.TryParse(lblServerDateTime.Text, out d);
        d = d.AddDays(1);
        lblServerDateTime.Text = d.ToString("dd MMMM");
        calCurrentDay.SelectedDate = d;
    }

protected void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Up button click will decrease the date by one day
        DateTime d;
        DateTime.TryParse(lblServerDateTime.Text, out d);
        d = d.AddDays(-1);
        lblServerDateTime.Text = d.ToString("dd MMMM");
        calCurrentDay.SelectedDate = d;
    }
```

Comment: May I ask how to link these codes with the calendar? 
so whenever the user decrease the date or increase the date using the arrows; the (SelectedDay) will move as well in the calendar. 
note that I'm using a style for the SelectedDay >> SelectedDayStyle

Comment: <asp:Calendar ID="calCurrentDay" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" TitleStyle-Font-Bold="true" OnSelectionChanged="cal1_SelectionChanged" 
                     style="position: absolute;bottom: 380px; right: 480px;">
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#FFE271" BorderColor="#FFCC00" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#DEEDB9" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Black" />
                </asp:Calendar>

Comment: I need to show the current date as highlighted in deffault also

Comment: GREAT thanks! , what about setting the current date as highlighted by default ?

Comment: calCurrentDay.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: no I was trying to run it :s , I don't know where to put it ? 
it's not running 
Sorry I'm a beginner on C#